# lifetime of a temporary object when passed as an argument to std::move

Tags: c++

Can somebody explain how the lifetime of a temporary object gets affected when (and not) is passed as an argument to `std::move`. In the below code I'm creating r-value references using with and without `std::move`. And to my surprise I didn't get expected results.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout << "const" << std::endl;
    }

    A(A&& a) {
        std::cout << "move const" << std::endl;
    }

    ~A() {
        std::cout << "dest" << std::endl;
    }
};

void fn(A&& a) {
    std::cout << "inside fn" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    A&& a_ref = std::move(A());
    fn(std::move(A()));

    A&& a_ref1 = A();

    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
}
```

And this is the output I got

```
const
dest
const
inside fn
dest
const
end
dest
```

Comment: Which result did you not expect? Share the result you expected, why you expected them and how they differ from what you observed. Then we can help clear up any misconception you may have. As the question is now, we have to try to guess what you expected.

Comment: Show us what output you expected and why.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I expected the last `dest` to be printed before `end`. And also second `dest` to be printed before `inside fn`.

Comment: Like this? https://godbolt.org/z/Mx1G7K8nd

Comment: You can't extend the lifetime of a temporary object that goes through a function.  `A&& a_ref = std::move(A());` leaves `a_ref` as a dangling reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver Can you explain what's happening in case of `fn` function call.

Comment: @Harry don't describe your expected output but show it in the question.

Comment: IMO an rvalue reference variable (as opposed to a function parameter) should be considered ill-formed code.

Comment: @Harry I've added an answer to explain better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifetime extension of temporary objects does not work when you pass that temporary through a function.  When you do

```
A&& a_ref = std::move(A());
```

The rvalue reference that `A()` binds to is not `a_ref` but instead the parameter of `move`.  That parameter is destroyed when the fucntion ends, which means the temporary it is bound to will also be destroyed. This is why we see

```
const
dest
```

in the output and `a_ref` is a dangling refence.

With

```
fn(std::move(A()));
```

a temporary `A` is created from `A()` and `move` passes along a reference to that temporary to `fun`. The temporary is still bound to the parameter of `move` but since temporary objects live at least until the end of the full expression they were created in, `A()` will still be alive when we enter `fun`. The temporary will only be destroyed after `fun` ends which corresponds to the output of

```
const
inside fn
dest
```

Then with

```
A&& a_ref1 = A();
```

Here we are binding a temporary directly to an rvalue reference. This will extend the lifetime of the temporary to be the lifetime of the reference.  Since the reference is local to main, it is only "destroyed" once `main` ends, so that is why you see the output

```
const
end
dest
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is almost the same program, with some more information:

```
class A {
    std::string s;
public:
    A(std::string s1): s(std::move(s1)) {
        std::cout << "ctor for: " << s << std::endl;
    }

    A(A&& a) {
        std::cout << "move ctor for: " << a.s << std::endl;
    }

    ~A() {
        std::cout << "dtor for: " << s << std::endl;
    }
};

void fn(A&& a) {
    std::cout << "inside fn" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    A&& a_ref = std::move(A("1")); // life of temporary is not extended
    fn(std::move(A("2")));  // temporary is still alive when calling fn
    // above is essentially the same as just: fn(A("2"));
    A&& a_ref1 = A("3"); // life of temporary is extended
    A&& a_ref2 = std::move(A("4")); // life of temporary is not extended
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
}
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/xT9TcWvqh

Extending the lifetime of a temporary requires the temporary to be directly assigned to an rvalue or const lvalue reference. Which is the case with `A("3")` but is not the case of `A("1")` and `A("4")` which are not directly assigned to their reference, and thus their references do not extend their lifetime.

Output and explanation:

```
ctor for: 1
dtor for: 1    ==> the temporary is dead, life is not extended 
ctor for: 2
inside fn
dtor for: 2    ==> end of statement creating 2 (after calling fn)
ctor for: 3    ==> life of 3 is extended
ctor for: 4
dtor for: 4    ==> the temporary is dead, life is not extended 
end
dtor for: 3    ==> 3, whose life was extended is dead at the end of main
```